# How do I move content to another place in the DOM and then put it back?

Tags: javascript

I need by clicking on the "Forward" button to clone content from one DOM place and display it in another place. The first part of the problem was solved. But I also need that when I click on the button "Back" - the content has returned to its original place. Here are my results for now:

```js
const forward = document.getElementById('forward');

forward.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  const catContent = document.querySelectorAll('.category-content');
  
  catContent.forEach(item=>{
    item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
    const clonedContent = item.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('only-category').appendChild(clonedContent);
  })
  
})

const back = document.getElementById('back');

back.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  const catDubContent = document.querySelectorAll('.category-content');
  const serviceTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.service-title');
  
  catDubContent.forEach(item=>{
    item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
    let test = item.cloneNode(true);
    
    serviceTitle.forEach(item=>{
      item.appendChild(test);
    })
    
    console.log(test)
    
  })
  
})
```

```css
.content-wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
button{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.service-title{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <button id="forward" type="button">Forward</button>
  <button id="back" type="button">Back</button>
    
    <div id="grid-table">

      <div class="service-title" id="category-1">
      
      <h2>Service One</h2>
      
      <div class="category-content" id="category-1-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Sed enim in purus ultricies vitae metus.</p>
        <p>Et dolor fermentum nisi ligula</p>
        <p>Nisi eget varius nisi, eget nis</p>
      </div>
      
      </div>

      <div class="service-title" id="category-2">
        
        <h2>Service Two</h2>
        
        <div class="category-content" id="category-2-content">
          <p>Aenean sed enim in purus ultricies vitae metus.</p>
          <p>Nullam et dolor fermentum ligula</p>
          <p>Etiam eget varius nisi, eget fermentum nis</p>
        </div>
        
      </div>

  </div>

    <div id="only-category"></div>
    
  </div>
```

As you can see, the content does not return to its place.  I am not strong with JavaScript, and most likely I'm missing some little concept. Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-currying-vtrbu?file=/src/index.js)

My solution is to have an array of cloned categories which get pushed when they are added via the forward click.

Then when the back button is clicked, re-add the elements in their original positions and clear the array.

```js
const categories = [];

const forward = document.getElementById("forward");

forward.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const catContent = document.querySelectorAll(".category-content");

  if (categories.length === 0) {
    catContent.forEach((item) => {
      const clonedContent = item.cloneNode(true);

      categories.push({
        element: item.parentElement,
        content: clonedContent
      });

      item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
      document.getElementById("only-category").appendChild(clonedContent);
    });
  }
});

const back = document.getElementById("back");

back.addEventListener("click", function () {
  categories.forEach((category) => {
    category.element.appendChild(category.content);
  });
  categories.length = 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jhon! It's a really clear solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which is pretty straight forward and easy to understand (but may not be the cleanest) is to add a counter and append your html into your category-id divs.

```js
const forward = document.getElementById('forward');

forward.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  const catContent = document.querySelectorAll('.category-content');
  
  catContent.forEach(item=>{
    item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
    const clonedContent = item.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('only-category').appendChild(clonedContent);
  })
  
})

const back = document.getElementById('back');

back.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  const catDubContent = document.querySelectorAll('.category-content');

  let categoryId;
  let ctr = 1;
  
  catDubContent.forEach(item=>{
    item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
    let test = item.cloneNode(true);
    categoryId = document.querySelectorAll("#category-" + ctr);

    categoryId.forEach(item=>{
      item.appendChild(test);
    })
    
    ctr = ctr + 1;
    
    console.log(test)
    
  })
  
})
```

```css
.content-wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
button{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.service-title{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <button id="forward" type="button">Forward</button>
  <button id="back" type="button">Back</button>

  <div id="grid-table">

    <div class="service-title" id="category-1">

      <h2>Service One</h2>

      <div class="category-content" id="category-1-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Sed enim in purus ultricies vitae metus.</p>
        <p>Et dolor fermentum nisi ligula</p>
        <p>Nisi eget varius nisi, eget nis</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="service-title" id="category-2">

      <h2>Service Two</h2>

      <div class="category-content" id="category-2-content">
        <p>Aenean sed enim in purus ultricies vitae metus.</p>
        <p>Nullam et dolor fermentum ligula</p>
        <p>Etiam eget varius nisi, eget fermentum nis</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="only-category"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution from John, it is much cleaner. I have modified your solution, so you can see why it was not working.

After you moved the content from left to right, you deleted the divs as well -> that's why the content was not placed back into the orignal place (it did not exist anymore).

You need to adjust the `back.addEventListener` a little bit as well.

```js
const forward = document.getElementById('forward');

forward.addEventListener('click', function() {

  const catContent = document.querySelectorAll('.category-content');

  catContent.forEach(item => {
    const clonedContent = item.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById('only-category').appendChild(clonedContent);
    item.innerHTML = "";
  })

})

const back = document.getElementById('back');


back.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // original content 
  const gridTable = document.getElementById('grid-table');
  const originalDubContentDivs = gridTable.querySelectorAll('.category-content');


  // copied content 
  const onlyCategory = document.getElementById('only-category');
  const catDubContent = onlyCategory.querySelectorAll('.category-content');

  const serviceTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.service-title');

  catDubContent.forEach((item, index) => {
    originalDubContentDivs[index].innerHTML = item.innerHTML;
    item.innerHTML = "";
    item.parentNode.removeChild(item);

  })

})
```

```css
.content-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.service-title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <button id="forward" type="button">Forward</button>
  <button id="back" type="button">Back</button>

  <div id="grid-table">

    <div class="service-title" id="category-1">

      <h2>Service One</h2>

      <div class="category-content" id="category-1-content">
        <p>Category 1 content Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Sed enim in purus ultricies vitae metus.</p>
        <p>Et dolor fermentum nisi ligula</p>
        <p>Nisi eget varius nisi, eget nis</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="service-title" id="category-2">

      <h2>Service Two</h2>

      <div class="category-content" id="category-2-content">
        <p>Category 2 content Aenean sed enim in purus ultricies vitae metus.</p>
        <p>Nullam et dolor fermentum ligula</p>
        <p>Etiam eget varius nisi, eget fermentum nis</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="only-category"></div>

</div>
```